# Calculating sum of field in all matching documents - MongoDB - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a Mongoose aggregation query to get the sum of a field for all matching documents.

Meaning I have a model that looks like:

```
{
    itemNumber: String,
    quantity: Number

}
```

There are multiple documents with the same itemNumber, I'm looking to get the sum of the quantity fields.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$itemNumber",
      count: {
        $sum: "$quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AvfvBladZmn)